# JavaFX 11 fxml TableView Fails to Populate

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have been endeavouring to implement a TableView using data generated in the initialize() method of the Controller and a user interface provide by the fxml.

However, the TableView fails to poulate and displays an empty view with the message 'No content in table'.

Consequently I have created a simplified application as follows.
If anybody can suggest what I may have omitted it will be much appreciated.

Controller

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TableView tvNicknames;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn tcName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn tcNickname;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        ObservableList<DataModel> nickList =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new DataModel(new SimpleStringProperty("Alan"), new SimpleStringProperty("Pip")),
                        new DataModel(new SimpleStringProperty("Bertie"), new SimpleStringProperty("Beets")),
                        new DataModel(new SimpleStringProperty("Charlie"), new SimpleStringProperty("Collie")),
                        new DataModel(new SimpleStringProperty("Dave"), new SimpleStringProperty("Daffy")),
                        new DataModel(new SimpleStringProperty("Ernie"), new SimpleStringProperty("Einstein"))
                );

        //specify cell factories for each TableColumn
        tcName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        tcNickname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nickname"));



    }


}
```

DataModel

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class DataModel {

    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private SimpleStringProperty nickname;

    public DataModel() {
    }

    public DataModel(SimpleStringProperty name, SimpleStringProperty nickname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nicknameProperty() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname.set(nickname);
    }
}
```

fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<FlowPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">

    <TableView fx:id="tvNicknames" prefWidth="250" prefHeight="200">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="tcName" text="Name" prefWidth="100"/>
            <TableColumn fx:id="tcNickname" text="Nickname" prefWidth="100" />
        </columns>
    </TableView>

</FlowPane>
```

Comment: you never set the item ;)

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to add the list to the `TableView`. You basically need to add the following line to method `initialize` in class `Controller`.

```java
tvNicknames.setItems(nickList);
```

In your `DataModel` class, you don't need a default constructor. I removed it. Also, I prefer to send property values to the constructor and instantiate properties in the constructor. Hence I changed the other constructor in class `DataModel`. I don't know if it's better, it just feels more correct to me. Here is `DataModel` class with my changes.

```java
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class DataModel {
    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private SimpleStringProperty nickname;

    public DataModel(String name, String nickname) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name", name);
        this.nickname = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "nickname", nickname);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nicknameProperty() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname.set(nickname);
    }
}
```

Here is `Controller` class with the fix that I described above. Notice also that the creation of the list has changed because of the change to the `DataModel` constructor. Also I added type parameters to the types for the variables. Again, not mandatory, but I feel that it is more correct.

```java
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TableView<DataModel> tvNicknames;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DataModel, String> tcName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<DataModel, String> tcNickname;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        ObservableList<DataModel> nickList =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new DataModel("Alan", "Pip"),
                        new DataModel("Bertie", "Beets"),
                        new DataModel("Charlie", "Collie"),
                        new DataModel("Dave", "Daffy"),
                        new DataModel("Ernie", "Einstein")
                );
        tvNicknames.setItems(nickList); // ADDED THIS LINE

        //specify cell factories for each TableColumn
        tcName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        tcNickname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nickname"));
    }
}
```

Of-course I created a class that extends `javafx.application.Application` in order to test the above code. Here is the code of that class.
Note that I named the FXML file *nickname.fxml* and I did not change anything in it. It is the same as in your question.

```java
package sample;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NickName extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        URL location = getClass().getResource("nickname.fxml");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(location);
        FlowPane root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer. It is much appreciated. All good now